# Checkbox becomes required when radio button is checked

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to write jQuery code to to valiate if a certain radio button is checked.
If that radio button is checked,4 checkboxes appear,and at least one of them must be checked.
If not,browsers shows the alert,in the other case,the form is sent.

The problem is that even if I select a checkbox i get the browser alert that I didn't checked any checkbox,and ofc the form won't submit.
Thx in advance.

HTML:

```
<form method='POST' action='#'>
        <input type='radio' id='D_odg' name='c' value=''>

        <div id='D_div'>

            <input type='checkbox' value='1' name='c3' id='inputD1'><label>Label1</label>
            <input type='checkbox' value='2' name='c3' id='inputD2'><label>Label2</label>
            <input type='checkbox' value='3' name='c3' id='inputD3'><label>Label3</label>
            <input type='checkbox' value='4' name='c3' id='inputD4'><label>Label4</label>

        </div>

        <input type='submit' value='Send' id='button'>

</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    var checkedboxes = $('.D_div :checkbox:checked').length;
    if ($('#D_odg').prop('checked') && checkedboxes===0{
          alert('At least 1 checkbox must be selected');
          return false;               
     }else{
          alert('Form submited!');
     }           
});
```

Comment: `.` is for class while `#` is for id. your selector differs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few Issues with your code.

1) You have incorrect selector to target parent div of checkboxes. `D_div` is id of div and not class. Thus you need to use id selector `#` instead of class selector `.`:

```
var checkedboxes = $('#D_div :checkbox:checked').length;
                    //^^  ID selector here
```

2) You have syntax error. You haven't used closing braces for if condition

```
if ($('#D_odg').prop('checked') && checkedboxes===0)
                                                // ^^ missing brace
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u9ymnesx/)**

Comment: @Prism: glad it helps :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this : you have used class selector instead of id selector for `D_div`. Also you may change `$('#D_odg').prop('checked')` to `$('#D_odg').is(':checked')` which looks more readable, see below code

```
$('#button').click(function () {

        var checkedboxes = $('#D_div :checkbox:checked').length;

         if ($('#D_odg').is(':checked') && checkedboxes===0){
          alert('At least 1 checkbox must be selected');
          return false;

         }else{

          alert('Form submited!');

         }           

    });
```

Comment: prop returns value along with its type. `prop('checked')` and `is(':checked')` will return same values.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar oh ok .. i did not know that. Thanks for correction

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the closing parenthesis after ===0. Also the :checkbox:checked was returning 0. This works:

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    var checkedboxes = $('[name="c3"]:checked').length;
    if ($('#D_odg').prop('checked') && checkedboxes===0){
        alert('At least 1 checkbox must be selected');
        return false;
    }else{
        alert('Form submited!');
    }           
});
```